# Not able to run the java example of WordCount-Compiler issue

Tags: java, hadoop

Mentioned below is the error that i am getting when trying to execute the java version of the WordCout. I was able to compile the same successfully but i am not able to figure out why it is cribbing now. i tried all combinations of the library path, thinking some dependency issue, but still stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/hadoop# java -cp lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar . /src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/WordCount
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: .. Program will exit.
root@ubuntu:/opt/hadoop#.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .`

`java` is trying to tell you that it cannot find the class named `.`

Answer (score 1):

When you run a Java program, you need to specify the actual class you are executing. What you have so far is this:

```
java -cp lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar .
```

All this is saying is that these two JARs should be in the CLASSPATH, and that you are trying to run some class called "`.`"  There is of course no such class named "`.`"  The `.` should be the name of the class you are trying to run, not a `.` .  That class should have a `main()` method inside of it.

Comment: The file to be executed is mentioned, it got hidden because of the scroll bar :)

Comment: Several issues here.  You have a space between the `.` and the rest of the path to the class (`/src/examples/...`)  Remove the space.  But also, you cannot specify a class to execute using a filesystem path.  The class must be in your `CLASSPATH`.  You could either add `/src/examples` to your CLASSPATH, or `cd` into `/src/examples` and run from there.  Either way, the class should be specified as `org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it removing "." in your command.

Answer (score 0):

Because the WordCount example is meant to launch a MapReduce job, it's intended to be run with the following:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar wordcount [-m <#maps>] [-r <#reducers>] <in-dir> <out-dir>
```

This will set up the classpath for you.

See http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount